# Formula to Exclude Current Month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to find the average of a running list with values broken down by month.
The problem I'm having is excluding the current month from the formula.

I've tried using `=indirect` and `=counta`, but only got errors.

The closest I've been able to get is by using the sum and divide method, but it does not produce consistently accurate results.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YH8vlvGAoZ9Z-uJTdesgmhX8t6pz3JoEhqi4t9-APSE/edit?usp=sharing

Any guidance is appreciated. The sheet is open for comments if it is easier to answer that way.

Comment: Welcome. Thank you for including your Google sheet. Would you please advise two things: 1) there are three sheets containing data, which is the "running list" that you wish to average/month. and 2) Please supply an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Hi there.  Could you make the sheet editable instead of comment only so that a couple of different solutions can be tested and demo'ed?

Comment: @Tedinoz My apologies, those additional sheets were from my "live" document. I have deleted them. My hope was to learn the correct formula on this simplified file and then apply to the "live" one myself. By "running list," I meant there will be additional ROWs added as time goes by, so I would like the formula to always exclude the current month when calculating average.

Comment: @MattKing Sheet has been made editable. Thank you.

Comment: @MattKing I've updated link in original posting and edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Its' a little more than what you're specifically asking here, but maybe this gets at what you're really going for.  Take a look at a new tab called MK.help where you will find this single formula in cell A1 that populates the whole table.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFERROR(EOMONTH(Expenses!A:A,-1)+1),Expenses!B:C},"select Col1,AVG(Col2) where Col1<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)&" and Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3 label Col1'Month-Year'"))
```

Comment: I goofed and placed incorrect Google Sheet in original posting. Link has been corrected in original question.

Comment: Outstanding formulating! You have finally helped me understand the application of ARRAY. Thank you. I made a royal mess of Google Sheet links on this question, so here is Matt's solution: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qoprq_shO5WOg1gyJSJnDnBp5zpw-ECGkcqURq2uqi0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If @MattKing has help you to come with a solution consider upvote his answer or accepting if it indeed solved your issue.